# Best Solution to use CountDownTimer inside SensorManager(Barometer)

Tags: android, countdowntimer, sensormanager

I need some simple logic to resolve this problem. So here is what i want :

The value of barometer range is etc 31,xxxx - 33,xxxx. So if the barometer value outside range of 31,xxxx - 33,xxxx , the countdowntimer is start counting.

But if the value is return inside again, the countdowntimer will be onPause(). And when the value is outside of that range, the countdowntimer will be start again. And so on.

So if the timer is onFinish(), the system will give some alert, but if not finish the system will not give anything response.

Here is my code :

```
public SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            float pressure_value = 0.0f;
            float height = 0.0f;
            if (Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE == event.sensor.getType())
            {
                pressure_value = event.values[0];
                height = SensorManager.getAltitude(SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE, pressure_value);
            }
            value = String.valueOf(height);
            valueOftxtBaro = Float.parseFloat(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare a global variable of the time and the Timer for example 30secs.

```
private int time = 30000;
private CountDownTimer cdt;
```

Multiply it to 1000 so it will be 30000. Now inside your Sensor start a timer when it gets your range.

```
  cdt =  new CountDownTimer(time, 1000, getActivity().getApplicationContext()) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    super.onTick(millisUntilFinished);

                    time = millisUntilFinished;

                }


                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    super.onFinish();
                }
            }.start();
```

When it did not get the range

```
 if(cdt != null){
 cdt.cancel();
 }
```

That's it you may do anything you want with the onFinish method when the timer runs out.